# How to write mathematical symbols such as $\sum_{i=n}^\mathbb{N}$ with indices below/above the $\sum$

Tags: support, mathjax, formatting

I want to write:

$\cup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$, and $\sum_{i=n}^\mathbb{N}$. But I want them the index to be above and below the symbol, not to the side, how do I fix this?

Comment: Let me just say that using $\mathbb N$ as the upper bound for a sum is very unusual. I'd say that $\sum\limits_{i=n}^N$ or $\sum\limits_{i=n}^\infty$ are what I would have expected there.

Comment: @Martin: Or $\sum\limits_{n\in\Bbb N}$.

Comment: Please avoid doing this in titles. It takes too much vertical space on the homepage, and it's unfair to others.

Comment: To expand on what @AymanHourieh wrote: There is a post about [Guidelines for good use of $\LaTeX$ in question titles](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9687/guidelines-for-good-use-of-latex-in-question-titles)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `\limits` to get that as in $\sum\limits_{i=n}^\mathbb{N}\frac1{i^2}$. However, this severely messes with the interline spacing.

code: `\sum\limits_{i=n}^\mathbb{N}\frac1{i^2}`

You can also use `\displaystyle` as in $\displaystyle\sum_{i=n}^\mathbb{N}\frac1{i^2}$. However, this *really* messes with interline spacing.

code: `\displaystyle\sum_{i=n}^\mathbb{N}\frac1{i^2}`

Comment: Considering the examples in the OP, it is also worth mentioning that \cup cannot be used together with limits, one has to use \bigcup instead: $\bigcup\limits_{n\in\mathbb N}$ `$\bigcup\limits_{n\in\mathbb N}$`.

Comment: @MartinSleziak: good point, I didn't notice they were using $\cup$. However, they could use $\operatorname{\cup}\limits_{i=1}^\infty$ or $\operatorname*{\cup}_{i=1}^\infty$.