# How to type Sigma and other symbols in MathJax

Tags: discussion, support, mathjax

Can someone please illustrate how to use the sigma symbol using mathjax and other such symbols please help? 
By the way the moderators of this site are extremely helpful so thank you.

Comment: Type \Sigma inside dollar signs: $\Sigma$. Search for mathjax tutorials and detexify.

Comment: Type \$\Sigma\$

Comment: See also: [How to markup expression using sigma notation for sum in MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/22443) and [How to write mathematical symbols such as $\sum_{i=n}^\mathbb{N}$ with indices below/above the $\sum$](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13519).

Comment: The $5$ negative votes (and counting) are because this question is considered to be "*too easy to answer*". If you feel that the question is beneath you, then go back to your search results and find a question you like better. Most people will tell you to read the [$\mathcal{MathJax} Guide$](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). However, the guide is more than 80 pages long when printed on physical paper. There is no need to throw the book at someone when they only want to know how to do one simple thing.

Answer (score 7):

\$\Sigma\$ produces

> $\Sigma$

\$\Sigma_{n=1}^\infty\$ produces

> $\Sigma_{n=1}^\infty$

\$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\$ produces

> $\sum_{n=1}^\infty$

and \$\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty\$ produces

> $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty$